# Calculate $\ P(X+Y>1|Y>1/2)$. Both variables are uniformly distributed.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

The information given in the task:

*X and Y are independent random variables.

$\ X$~$R(0,1)$

$\ Y$~$R(0,1)$*

I am then told to calculate:

$P(X>1/4)$, expected values and so on. The last problem is the one I am struggling with:

*Calculate $P(X+Y>1|Y>1/2)$, (The solution is 3/4)*

Somehow I'm unable to solve this. My idea is:

Given that both X and Y are uniformly distributed I know that their PDF's are:

$\ f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{b-a}, x \in [a,b]$

$\ f_X(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}, x \in [a,b]$

Since;

$\ X$~$R(0,1)$

$\ Y$~$R(0,1)$

we get:

$\ f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{1-0}, x \in [0,1]$

$\ f_X(x)=\frac{1}{1-0}, x \in [0,1]$

Since this problem is dealing with conditional I thought I would use the formula

$\ f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$

Since $f_Y(y)$ is already calculated I need $f_{XY}(x,y)$

Since X and Y are independent the definition of this independence gives me:

$f_Y(y)·f_X(x)=f_{XY}(x,y)$

So:

$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-0}·\frac{1}{1-0}=1$

This means:

$\ f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$

My idea is then to use the formula

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

$P(B)=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{1}{1-0}dy=\frac{1}{2}$

But how do I proceed from here when neither of the pdf's have any variables in them? Given that the integrals that I need to solve has to depend on X or Y I keep getting the wrong solutions when trying to solve it. In other words, im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X+Y>1,Y>1/2)=P(X>1-Y,Y>1/2)=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\int_{1-y}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dx dy=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\int_{1-y}^{1}f_{X}(x)dx \;f_Y(y)dy=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} y \, dy=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{3}{8}.$
So since we know that $P(Y>1/2)=1/2$ you find:
$$P(X+Y>1|Y>1/2)=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: this solution is the same as the other one, which is faster but maybe you need to have some experience to see that immediately.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I see that, once again annoyingly, it was the limits that I had gotten wrong. I've added your limits and reasoning to my calculations, and the correct answer pops right out.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the square with vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Then graphically
$$
P(X+Y>1|Y>1/2)=\frac{P(X+Y>1, Y>1/2)}{P(Y>1/2)}=\frac{1/2-1/8}{1/2}=\frac{3}{4}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Combined with the additional information given by Chak I managed to solve the task.